# Is Managed Resource Group Mandatory for creating Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

while creating Azure Databricks, the managed resource group is getting created automatically with resources(vnet,nsg and storage account). My question is, is it possible to create Azure Databricks without managed resource group. If not can we use our existing resources(like vnet, nsg and storage account)

I have tried creating Azure Databricks with rest APi with empty managed resource group. But i am not able to sign in while launching workspace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The managed resource group must exist as this is where your cluster(s) will be created. To ensure that nothing breaks them, they are placed in a separate resource group that has a super lock on it so you cannot modify anything in it.

There is however the ability to deploy into your own vnet (currently in public Preview) https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/administration-guide/cloud-configurations/azure/vnet-inject.html

Note that the Managed Resource Group is still created and required when you do this.

Comment: thanks for the reply @simon_dmorias . can i provide my own naming convention for the resources which are getting created inside the managed resource group.

Comment: Afraid not. Do the names matter? People get very hung up on naming. I take the view of naming things how you want, don't even be that consistent. Treat resources as cattle not babies. The only exception is Resource Groups, as a logic grouping a good naming convention is required.

Comment: yes, you can give a name to the managed resource group as per your naming convention. Just define property "ManagedResourceGroupId" in ARM Template
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
"properties": {
                "ManagedResourceGroupId": "[variables('managedResourceGroupId')]",.

Comment: Is there documentation that explains what a Managed Resource Group is (vs a regular ARM Resource Group?) -- since they both have the same words in the name, the documentation search is highly problematic (i.e. pretty much everything just links you back to things like the Management of Azure Resource Groups).  The little info bubble is also unhelpful as the definition it provides assumes a base line level of understanding. -- I would love to learn more about this topic.