# Tag a Managed Resource Group for Azure Databricks

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, azure-databricks

Given that [managed resource groups are mandatory for creating an Azure Databricks cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55704705/is-managed-resource-group-mandatory-for-creating-azure-databricks), is there any way that I can tag the resource group in order to comply with the tagging policy on my subscription?

I am using the template [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/101-databricks-workspace/azuredeploy.json) to deploy my resources.

Comment: Are you using powershell, if yes you can do this easily after deployment. The only other way would be to add the Resource group within the template itself

Answer (score 1):

Any tags that you use when creating the Databricks workspace will be used for the managed resource group as well so just make sure you add the needed tags to the workspace when creating it. I know this works when creating the workspace from the Azure Portal but I can't see any reason this wouldn't work when using ARM templates (or Terraform for that matter).

Also, I'm also pretty sure that future changes will be propagated to said resource group.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [post](https://blog.nillsf.com/index.php/2020/04/07/tag-resources-created-by-a-databricks-cluster/) I found:,

> Since Feb 10 2020, the Databricks resource will propagate any tags applied to the Databricks resource to the managed resources it created.

I think the solution is more simpler now by tagging Databricks resource directly.
Hope this answer (by others) works for everyone seeing this post.